Is 'Negative Prophecy' a reviewed, acknowledged teaching of any Christian tradition?
Recently, I heard a pastor in a meeting use the term "negative prophecy", who immediately started listing examples to justify it (like a 5-second conversation SysTheo summary). He said that "negative prophecy" was limited to the Old Testament, but was not in the New Testament, and that Jesus's negative statements were only against Pharisees and a secular Jewish government. That seemed like strange reasoning, but that is background, not my question. I'm curious about the actual concept and term "negative prophecy".
Is negative prophecy even a real term used in any actual tradition's teaching?
I had never heard of "negative prophecy" in any Christian teaching before, so I did some search with Google, and these were from top results:
Examples

Negative prophecies shall fail.


Every negative word spoken against you; every negative prophecy concerning you, your life, your destiny; shall fail;, they will not stand in Jesus mighty name! Amen...


HOW TO CANCEL NEGATIVE PROPHECIES AND DREAMS


Vision can be canceled by prayer and saturated with the word of God.


REJECT NEGATIVE PROPHECIES


THOUGHT FOR THE DAY: Never respect anyone enough to allow them drive your destiny in a negative direction. ...the “prophet” in question said something negative concerning our going to that country for the crusade. It was a negative prophecy and according to them, the so-called prophet usually prophesied accurately.


YOU WILL NOT FULFIL (sic) NEGATIVE PROPHECIES


There are both positive and negative prophecies in the Bible. Some people fulfilled good prophecies while some fulfilled bad prophecies. Also, nowadays, some prophets and those who claim to be prophets give positive and negative prophecies. In the past, some people have fulfilled positive prophecies while others have fulfilled negative prophecies.


What do I do if I get a negative Prophetic word for someone?


...what you do when you get something negative is to switch the thought 180 degrees. He replied that he couldn’t flip it to a positive as it was just so black and dark. ...the person... was having a psychotic episode during the weekend and was admitted to a psychiatric ward. That is an extreme when I talk about getting a negative word for someone.


NEGATIVE PROPHECY


Friend, hear me as I hear the Lord: you will not fulfill negative prophecies. You will not be an example of one who suffered a disaster that was foretold. You will not be an example of those who experienced negativity. You will not be an example of those whose lives turned upside down as a result of negativities that were foretold. You will not be swallowed by negative experiences. You will not be a partaker of future negativity.


Video: Pray for the continent of Asia! When there is a negative prophecy, it is revealed by God so the church can pray and annul it.


I've seen something in the Spirit: I see a disease coming... It's coming... Let's pray: Divine protection... This disease coming to the earth, Lord, keep your people. Protect your own, in the name of Jesus Christ. I pray for those in Asia, this break, this break, this war with water, with nature, with ground opening, this eruption... They will lay human beings as dogs, we pray for protection of lives... I pray a protection upon you...

These reflect the same context in which the pastor used the term during that meeting.
The pastor and these search results having used the term consistently, I am curious where so many people got this term? Did they get it from a church tradition's teaching? Or, did these authors and speakers merely get it from each other?

The alternatives?
It seems this may be a homily instead of a theology or doctrine. It only seems to appear in blogs and sermons, rather than actual statements of faith, confessions, or catechisms. I can't even find books about "negative prophecy" searching on Amazon or Barnes & Noble. I would think that if this is a real thing, some publisher would have agreed.
Not finding the term in doctrine or even book stores, what is the purpose for using it?
Scope
This term specifically applies to beliefs within Continuationism. This term would not apply to Cessationism, which generally rejects any and all forms of prophecy, among other things, after the Apostolic Age.
Application & usage
It seems that the term "negative prophecy" creates a logical category of a specific type of prophecy for the purpose of 1. identifying a given prophecy as falling within a sub-category of prophecy in order to 2. respond to that specific prophecy so-placed within this sub-category. From the use and literature I can find, these responses are only one of the following two:

Reject as invalid
Pray against

Across the board, responses specifically do not include, and may even reject, any suggestion of:

Call to new/change action
Call to repentance for sinful causes
Call to trust/thank God for protecting/chastening
Call to courage/patience to endure

Where this term "negative prophecy" is used, the driving purpose seems to reflect a utilitarian intent to make a categorical denial of what the prophecy claims.
Where the term is used
It seems to be used wherever the writer or speaker is attracting views, readers, shares, likes, parishioners, donations, book sales (from the author), and other things affected by marketing. So, the term almost seems to be part of a non-profit/church marketing strategy (viz craft your message and selling points).
Is it?
Motive for teaching such non-doctrine
Is this really nothing more than fancy Bible-ish jargon meant to drive sales, views, and donations? That would be a wild claim, but I can't find any other demonstrable purpose driving its wide-spread use. Nor, can I find any doctrinal origin.
If it isn't a church teaching anywhere, why are Christian bloggers and speakers using the term? (This question is genuinely asking for any alternate explanation.)
It is interesting to consider the two categories of scope because the Cessationist can easily dismiss any prophecy, merely on the basis of it being a prophecy. But, the Continuationist using the term "negative prophecy" may like the idea of God talking, as long as "the prophecy doesn't have a 'negative' mental attitude"—both uses of "negative" being extrabiblical concepts, and seemingly extra-doctrinal as well. Is that all this is about? I am stretching to find some other explanation, but can't.
This almost seems as if the term "negative prophecy" is a tool for people with passive aggression to dismiss ideas they don't like, as if they need a have your cake and eat it too tool: they believe in God speaking through prophecy, but they want a seemingly-academic reason to dismiss a prophecy they disagree with, even if the prophecy may be otherwise legitimate.

So, what is "Negative Prophecy"?
This question has two parts.

Primarily: Does this term originate from any church traditional doctrine?
Secondarily: If not, is there another explanation?


Is the term a pop-culture homily geared toward "positive mental attitude" -driven marketing?
Or, is this something else?


Hi Jesse, fancy to see you here in my usual haunt.  I'm surprised that this is your first question.  Feel strange to say this since you're so established in BH.SE, but Welcome to C.SE !

Glad you've brought this up as I'd never heard of it before (but then, given the circles I mix in, that was never going to be likely!) Re. your point, "If it isn't a church teaching anywhere, why are Christian bloggers and speakers using the term?". The answer to that might be, because Christians are blogging instead of delving into church teaching. Mainstream, orthodox teaching has given way to a free-for-all on the Internet, with number of "Likes" having more clout than what the Bible says. Will follow this Q with interest.

@GratefulDisciple the reason I haven't "hauted" this place with you was because, for some reason back in the day, it didn't do Systematic Theology for answers. Everything had to be based in Church History, which was not my strong point. But since, I noticed more recently that some of our own usual suspects come here to ask, more or less, for SysTheo defenses of specific doctrines. So, I'm pleased to say I just might go write up some of my own answers now.

@Anne Pleasure to see another friendly name also. Indeed it is seeming more and more that way. With a mass exodus from Sunday institutions, as observed by George Barna as early as 2005, many seem to have decided to ignore all the study that came before them.

I was not able to discern the denomination underlying each of the links provided in the OP.  Some of the organizations represented were not even very forthcoming on their websites regarding their particular theological leanings, whether conservative, liberal, pentecostal, etc.  I am listing them all below in the order in which they are given in OP along with what I have discovered.  Perhaps others can add to this answer wiki style.
God's Solution Ministries - In Barrie, Ontario Canada.  They seem to hold the prime, traditional Christian doctrines and to be Evangelical and Charismatic.  Pastor is ordained in unspecified denomination and has connection to Nigeria.
HCC Solution Arena - Lagos Nigeria.  The website link brought up by a google search leads to what appears to be a medical facility.  The Solution Arena is all over all the major social media venues.  They appear to be quite Pentecostal/Word of Faith ish.
Dunamis Gospel Center - Abuja, Nigeria.  Possibly now defunct due to structural collapse of the "Glory Dome" in 2023.  Religion listed as "worldwide".  "Name it and claim it" style teaching seems most likely.
Cedar Ministries - Abuja, Nigeria.  International, "para-church" ministry.  Much the same as all of the above.
Unlocking the Gold Ministries - Currently Melbourne Australia.  Church of Christ ordination and current affiliation with Stairway Church (of which I could find very little).  Some training in South Africa and much emphasis on "healing rooms" and "unlocking God's potential within".
Streams of Joy International - Abuja, Nigeria.  More of the same.
Giftens Church - Lagos, Nigeria.  More of the same.
The connection to Nigeria is obviously overwhelming and I don't have much to say specifically about that.  More generally, I have been to Sierra Leone, South Africa on two occasions and was consistently struck at the wholesale marketing of the Gospel message there.  Not to say that there was not genuine faith as well but there were a great many "evangelists" and "ministries" who would advertise scheduled appearances of the Holy Spirit and if one would just attend and 'be generous' all manner of miracles would take place.  I attended many a "Church" service where the collection plate was passed 7, 8, even 10 times.
These people were, in large part, dollar-a-day poor with close familial ties to a mish-mash of animism, spiritism, Isalm, Christianity, voodoo, and who knows what else.  Many claimed allegiance to multiple religions equally;  hedging their bets, as it were.  For example, Charismatic Catholic Animists and Christian Muslims were not rare in Freetown.
They were desperately poor, uneducated (I do not say unintelligent), short-lived (50 yrs being old for a male).  The snake oil style selling of the "Gospel" was a very tempting way out of a doomed lifestyle and it was made easy by an almost universal ignorance of the Biblical text.
One genuine Pastor I spent some time with was completely illiterate and relied on his young children to read passages to him for study and to the congregation for preaching.  There is a pastoral training ministry and a strong radio presence there trying to overcome Pastoral illiteracy for those who are not "going for the gold".
That these same types of "Ministries" are growing such an online presence in the world is cause for caution.  Holyghost Christian Center (the HCC Solution Arena), for example, has a sizeable campus in New Jersey, USA as well as Texas, Pennsylvania, Indiana, and Cameroon, Africa.
The internet has given us everything anywhere.  This can be used for both good and bad just like any other tool and I don't assign any blame there, really.  I tentatively attribute this type of acceptance and growth of this 'prosperity gospel' type ministry to two things:

Primarily, a growing lack of confidence in and knowledge of the Biblical text.

The commensurate growth of "new-age' spirituality, and age old occultism, mysticism, paganism, Wicca, etc.


When the truth is absent, something else will be believed.  Every person worships something.  As Bob Dylan sang, "Gotta Serve Somebody".

This is amazingly helpful! I want to ask about a very technical point: When you say charismatic, are you identifying that as the movement that crystalized in 1967 in a Notre Dame revival, specifically distinguished from pentecostal, the revival that began on Asuza St in 1906?

@Jesse Glad to hear it!  I'm just using charismatic in the more general sense of especially emphasizing spiritual giftedness rather than baptism in the Spirit and tongues particularly.

@Jesse I really think that what presents as charismatic in that environment is really a bleed over from or an admixture of spiritism, animism, voodoo, witchcraft, etc. into nominally "christian" teaching.  Using the spirit rather than walking in the Spirit.  That's why it's entrance into wider circles is so very concerning.

Clarifying for disambiguation... Your definition of charismatic is indeed disturbing as it is real. So, you are not claiming that charismatic = Continuationism. Am I correct? This may need a separate question, but I understood "charismatic" churches to have come out of Notre Dame, or at least Pentecostals greatly influenced by Notre Dame. Do you have a specific word for non-charismatic Continuationism? Could Spiritist-charismatic be used instead of charismatic in your sense?

I almost wonder if a term spiritist-charismatic fits because my understanding of charismatics (vs pentecostals) is that they want "power demonstrated" (externally) and, but also carry an emphasis on "church authority", almost to a point of paranoid narcissism. So spiritism—the liturgical mix of Roman Catholicism with voodoo (the part you described) and "branding" and "using" the Holy Spirit rather than "walking"—fits. Maybe?

@Jesse I don't hate it.  Hard to put an accurate label on a hot mess :)

This needs a label because it includes a Napoleon Hill "positive-negative" lens for hermeneutics, along with Latter Reign theology, plus a mix of "PMA + prayer = get whatever I want, dangling God on a string" with influences from the book "The Secret". Having a positive attitude isn't bad and our thoughts affect our lives, but being so-called "positive" all the time won't re-write what God defines as "good, pleasing, perfect will", though these act as if it would. I'm ready to call it "spiritism" because of the voodoo/new-age influx to the doctrine and hermeneutics.

...And, for me, I don't want to use the term "charismatic" to only mean that over-done thing, but to be technical for the Spirit-baptism movement from the mid 1900s surrounding Notre Dame, because they are from Catholics and think like Catholics and are different from Pentecostals. That said, there seems to be a significant overlap between such charismatics and this charisma-spiritism. So, I think I may just go with charisma-spiritism to avoid cross-coloring my other markers. It employs rhetorical "charisma" as an impostor of the real HS "charis", after all.

@Jesse Charismatic movement seems to have begun within Anglicanism in 1960, into Lutheranism and Presbyterians in 1962 and then Catholicism in 1967.  I would put it in the category of continuationism, such that Charismatics are Continuationists but not all Continuationists are Charismatic.  Whatever label it is given (charisma-spiritism), it is essentially a money making scheme; a misuse of the gospel for filthy lucre's sake.  It is not the same as other denominational theological disagreements.  It is darkness.

That comment explains a lot, all of those are from reformed Catholic denominations, heavy on liturgy. Rectangles and squares, okay. Swindling, not theology, got it; a charisma-driven spiritist swindling scheme.

Do you have a specific link for that Charismatic development thru the 1960s, or can I search that one on my own? (Comments are mostly done, but they contribute importantly to this answer)

@Jesse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charismatic_movement

Not Christian; secular profit-driven philosophy?
Specifically, a means to enforce Latter Rain theology?
After 10 days, no answer has found any review from Christian tradition, either for or against. So, it might be in order to make a brief analysis for what would need to be addressed in a review, including some relationship to Bible passages.
I posted the question on Hermeneutics about whether this could be a valid means of interpreting Bible passages in general, specifically for this question about seeing Bible prophecy as "positive or negative". That Hermeneutics question provides some history of "positivity" and some Bible passages used along with it.
'Positivity' Origins
This concept does not seem to have Biblical or Theological roots, but comes as a philosophy from Napoleon Hill in his 1937 book Think and Grow Rich. Later, Hill with W. Clement Stone, popularized the term "Positive Mental Attitude" in the 1960 book Success Through a Positive Mental Attitude.
From Wikipedia (see footnotes)

Positive mental attitude is that philosophy which asserts that having an optimistic disposition in every situation in one's life attracts positive changes and increases achievement. 1 Adherents employ a state of mind that continues to seek, find and execute ways to win, or find a desirable outcome, regardless of the circumstances. This concept is the opposite of negativity, defeatism and hopelessness. Optimism and hope are vital to the development of PMA. 2
Positive mental attitude (PMA) is the philosophy of finding greater joy in small joys, to live without hesitation or holding back our most cherished, held in high esteem, and highest personal virtues and values. Empirical research suggests that individuals who engage in positive self-talk and maintain a mindful approach to their internal dialogues tend to exhibit greater self-control and resilience which is crucial for personal and professional growth, highlighting the significance of self-regulation and mindfulness in fostering a positive mental attitude. 3 Furthermore, research on leadership strategies suggest that a positive mental attitude, characterized by a proactive approach to personal and organizational challenges, significantly improves leadership effectiveness and success in leadership roles. 4

This is not a critique of "Positivity vs Negativity", but an observation of what it is and its origins.
This seems:

Recognizable for both the examples within the question (here from homily and from hermeneutics)
Rooted in non-religious philosophy of the early-mid 1900s
Centered on "wealth" and "success"

Profiteering & Spirit-Mysticism
Additionally, in Napoleon Hill's speeches, he claimed that he was commissioned to research and write the book by Andrew Carnegie, who complained about get money thinking being too much about morals, that...

We need an economic philosophy!

Positive Mental Attitude became Hill's newly discovered philosophy that Carnegie had wanted.
In the 1910s, Hill was accused of multiple scams, frauds, and businesses similar to MLM.
In his book, he describes having spirit visitations...

He described them as unseen friends, unseen watchers, strange beings, and the Great School of Masters that had been guarding him, and who maintain a "school of wisdom". Hill states that the "Master" spoke to him audibly, revealing secret knowledge.

So, the "Positive-Negative" lens has both profit-driven and sprit-mystical roots.
Connection to 'prosperity gospel'
On point 3, Got Questions has a few related articles:

What does the Bible say about the prosperity gospel?


Prosperity theology sees the Holy Spirit as a power to be put to use for whatever the believer wills.


Is the Word of Faith movement biblical?


Word of Faith teaching is decidedly unbiblical. It is not a denomination and does not have a formal organization or hierarchy. Instead, it is a movement that is heavily influenced by a number of high-profile pastors and teachers such as Kenneth Hagin, Benny Hinn, Kenneth Copeland, Paul and Jan Crouch, and Fred Price.

...That seems more like what we are looking at here, except this seems to have Charismatic roots while Word of Faith has Pentecostal roots...

The Word of Faith movement grew out of the Pentecostal movement in the late 20th century. Its founder was E. W. Kenyon, who studied the metaphysical New Thought teachings of Phineas Quimby. Mind science (where "name it and claim it" originated) was combined with Pentecostalism, resulting in a peculiar mix of orthodox Christianity and mysticism. Kenneth Hagin, in turn, studied under E. W. Kenyon and made the Word of Faith movement what it is today.

...So, secular philosophy influencing Christian preachers has happened before.

Is “name it claim it” teaching biblical?:


The “name it and claim it” or “prosperity gospel” is not biblical and is in many ways antithetical to the true gospel message and the clear teaching of Scripture. While there are many different versions of the name it and claim it philosophy preached today, they all have similar characteristics. At its best, this teaching comes from the misinterpretation and misunderstanding of some Scriptures, and, at its worst, it is a completely heretical teaching that has the characteristics of cultic doctrine.


Further reading: Rational Wiki: Name it claim it

Again, this is not a critique on wealth itself or whether God wants us to be rich or poor or healthy or healed by miracles, but on exploiting Christianity to present a quasi-Christian message for the purpose of profiteering.
Link to recent literature: possible motive
The Secret by Rhonda Byrne expands on Napoleon Hill's idea that thoughts can create our reality. She teaches that if we have strong and consistent good/positive thoughts, then we can have happier lives. Her emphasis is not on money as much as on contentment, but it includes the idea that thoughts can eventually bring wealth.
This expands on The Law of Attraction as taught by Joe Vitale. This idea is that one's thoughts will attract the results in one's life.
Both of these authors are part of a trend of authors and speakers teaching that we can get whatever we think about long and hard enough. Therefore we want only positive thoughts and not negative thoughts.
The spite for so-called "negative prophecy" may not be an actual theology, but an attempt to "remain positive in all things" after reading from the section of the book store with Byrne and Vitale.
Again, this is not a critique of those books or authors or their ideas, only the observation that this concept of "negativity vs positivity" is an extra-Biblical teaching and not a church doctrine. If treated as a church doctrine, then we have secular influence being passed along as if it were Christian teaching when it is merely from the culture. That will create problems down the road for people who don't recognize the difference.
Biblical Overlap
There is not an antithetical relationship between positive-negative and Christian/Bible doctine. There are several examples of consulting the Bible on dealing with "negative people", which does not require a "negative prophecy" doctrine.

Christianity.com: What Does the Bible Say about Toxic People?
Never Thirsty: How should we deal with a negative person?

Other Christian bloggers and websites express concern over applying the "positive-negative" lens to Bible and Christian teaching:

Culture Watch: On Being Negative or Positive


What should our emphasis be as believers? Should we only focus on the positive, or is there a place to also highlight the negative? For example, should we only talk about righteousness, goodness and God’s love, and so on, or should we also talk about sin and its damaging effects, judgment, etc?
Plenty of Christians believe we should only focus on the positive stuff, and just ignore the negative. They claim that the emphasis in the Bible is only on the positive, so we should also be doing this. But are they in fact correct?
...
They almost seem to think they can improve upon Scripture.

This looks deeper behind the obsession with "positivity", tracing back to psychology during the era of Napoleon Hill...

Association of Certified Biblical Counselors: The Negative Behind Positive Thinking


This idea that it’s okay to believe in yourself is part of this trick of the positive thinking movement that is very deceptive, and it’s killing us because it’s crept into the church. ...The positive thinking mindset is dangerous because it is a preoccupation with self, and it causes you to trust in yourself.
...the ideas of that preoccupation with self, where it leads us as well as some of the history behind the movement. E. Brooks Holifield believed that man had moved from self-denial to self-love, from self-love to self-culture, from self-culture to self-realization. In other words, through history man has been consumed with himself...
Many of these ideas for finding yourself and believing in yourself and man as basically good can be traced back to this human potential movement when people like Carl Rogers... Rogers believed that there was something good in man, and man needed to reach his potential. He needed to self-actualize... Maslow and his hierarchy of needs that came out of the human potential movement... man was basically good, and if he just looked within and followed his heart and worked hard at it, he could finally become all he wanted to be. Isn’t it sad that we hear a lot of that in the church today? It is based on the cultic idea that man is basically good.

Conflict with Bible passages
The argument and defense of the concept "negative prophecy" as presented, from the OP:

He said that "negative prophecy" was limited to the Old Testament, but was not in the New Testament, and that Jesus's negative statements were only against Pharisees and a secular Jewish government.

So, the rubric is: "negative prophecy" toward Pharisees and NT Israel government—any other "negative prophecy" does not exist in the New Testament.
Let's evaluate prophecies in the New Testament that are possibly "negative", or at least "less than positive".
This is where teachers of non-existent doctrine can get squirmy and change their terms to avoid being proven wrong. So, "less than positive" is an important boundary when looking for examples of "negative prophecy".
From The Archives Near Emmaus: Rob Bell, you’ve got to learn to give an answer.

I mentioned several times that he seemed “evasive”. That was most defining part of some of his answers.

'Negative Prophecy' in the New Testament
To Pharisees
Jesus prophesies "negatively" to pharisees
Matt 23:1-36 (NASB)

13 “But woe to you, scribes and Pharisees, hypocrites, because you shut the kingdom of heaven in front of people; for you do not enter it yourselves, nor do you allow those who are entering to go in.
15 “Woe to you, scribes and Pharisees, hypocrites, because you travel around on sea and land to make one proselyte; and when he becomes one, you make him twice as much a son of hell as yourselves.

Mark 12:38-40 (NASB) & Luke 20:45-47

Beware of the scribes who like to walk around in long robes... These will receive all the more condemnation.

Luke 11:37-52 (NASB)

Woe to you! For you are like unseen tombs, and the people who walk over them are unaware of it.

To the New Testament Israel Government
Matt 24:1-3 (NASB)

Do you not see all these things? Truly I say to you, not one stone here will be left upon another, which will not be torn down.

Elsewhere: Proven erroneous
Based on the defense for "negative prophecy" only existing in the Old Testament, or in the New Testament to Pharisees or New Testament secular Jewish government, these Bible passages present a problem...
Matt 24:6-7 (NASB)

6 And you will be hearing of wars and rumors of wars. See that you are not alarmed, for those things must take place, but that is not yet the end. 7 For nation will rise against nation, and kingdom against kingdom, and there will be famines and earthquakes in various places.

1 Tim 4:1 (NASB)

But the Spirit explicitly says that in later times some will fall away from the faith, paying attention to deceitful spirits and teachings of demons,

2 Tim 3:1-5 (NASB)

But realize this, that in the last days difficult times will come. 2 For people will be lovers of self, lovers of money, boastful, arrogant, slanderers, disobedient to parents, ungrateful, unholy, 3 unloving, irreconcilable, malicious gossips, without self-control, brutal, haters of good, 4 treacherous, reckless, conceited, lovers of pleasure rather than lovers of God, 5 holding to a form of godliness although they have denied its power; avoid such people as these.

2 Pet 2:1-2 (NASB)

But false prophets also appeared among the people, just as there will also be false teachers among you, who will secretly introduce destructive heresies, even denying the Master who bought them, bringing swift destruction upon themselves. 2  Many will follow their indecent behavior, and because of them the way of the truth will be maligned;

Let's look past the most sizable amounts of "negative prophecy" so that we don't need to quote the entire Book of Revelation.
This one passage is a kind of prophecy—not a prediction, but a message through John to the Church.
Rev 3:19 (NASB)

Those whom I love, I rebuke and discipline; therefore be zealous and repent.

The problem of definition
If this concept were reviewed, the matter of definition would need to be addressed...
In a Biblical-Chriatian worldview, what exactly is "negative" and "not positive"?
For example, if you are walking down the street and a bicycle slams into you, breaking your nose, but that stops you from stepping into a vat of hot tar, then the broken nose saved your life. Now, what if someone had a dream that would happen one day before it did, then told you? Would that be a "negative" or "positive" prophecy?
To Laodicea, God says He disciplines those He loves. Is that a negative or positive thing? What about someone singing in church when they suddenly hear the audible voice of the Lord say, "I will punish the pastor because I love him." Would that be negative or positive? A systheo of Rom 8:28 and Rev 3:19 would say it is "positive", but by many others already cited it would be "negative".
"Negitivity" and "positivity" are terms largely in the control of the beholder. At least they would need to be defined before applied objectively. This is the biggest problem with "negative prophecy"—it never defines the term "negative", but presumes that the hearer already knows the meaning.
And, it might not even exist at all.
Taking Romans 8:28, everything that happens to a Christian is good merely by the fact that it happened. This breaks the "negative-positive" paradigm because "negative" only happens to people who are not "called according to His purpose". God's Holy Spirit can't stop giving a kind of prophecy that doesn't even exist. This may be an imaginary classification altogether, let alone an imaginary sub-classification of prophecy.
So, from a Christian-Biblical Doctrine worldview, "negative prophecy" might not even exist for the Bible or any denomination to even agree or disagree with.
Connection to Latter Rain Theology
Latter Rain theology can be summarized as a personality-cult-like ecclesiology rationalized by an all-things-happy eschatology. It is controversial within Continuationism and may warrant a separate question, but there is important overlap.
After review and reflection, I recalled what another pastor at that group of churches had told me. It was in plain, no uncertain terms in a private conversation about what the church was teaching. This other pastor at the same church said with angst:

This is Latter Rain.

The examples from the original question aside, that pastor and his church indeed had a connection to Latter Rain theology.
Latter Rain has two main characteristics that distinguish its beliefs from others:

Heavy-handed leadership rationalized by "Manifested Sons of God" theology 5, 6:


...the manifested sons of God would appear in the church. They would be empowered with supernatural gifts and able to perform miracles comparable to the miracles ascribed to Jesus Christ in the New Testament. These Manifest Sons of God, ones who have come into the full stature of Jesus Christ, would receive the Spirit without measure.
...
Early leaders used Ephesians 4 to develop the idea that the manifestation of the sons of God could only be achieved through the leadership of specially endowed preachers operating as a "five-fold" ministry. In practice, this led to the creation of a strongly authoritarian leadership structure where members were required to submit themselves to the direction of their leaders for life guidance, decision making, and discipline.

...belief that these "sons of God" are not manifested by God directly, but they are appointed and cultivated at the Divinely anointed discretion of special church leaders.
This is based on the five-fold ministry idea that Ephesians 4:11 lists five things: Apostle, Prophet, Evangelist, Pastor, Teacher. However, based on Greek men... de (μέν... δέ) syntax, these may be four things: Apostle, Prophet, Evangelist, Shepard-Teacher. Taking the five-item interpretation, they teach that some special church leaders operate in all five, and they can decide—with God somehow working through them—who else can have any of these five gifts.
The five-item list is important for this "authoritarian leadership structure" because a "shepherd-teacher" is a personal, natural, god-given ability found in many people. But, a "pastor" is hired/appointed and a "teacher" can be approved or removed. So, the five-item categories are necessary for the leader to be able to exercise control.
Paul addresses the problem of so-called "super apostles" in 2 Cor 11:5. But already in Deut 18:15, God says that He raises up prophets from among our brothers. In Eph 4:11, Paul says that God gave these, with no mention of a special leader deciding. These passages create a problem for this doctrine, which is part of its controversy.

Signs and Wonders-flavored quasi Pre-trib Amillennialism 7:


The Latter Rain emphasized a victorious eschatological outlook. Rather than attempting to save a few souls before the rise of the anti-Christ, the Latter Rain emphasized the Church as overcoming and victorious, relating that it would come into "full stature" as taught by the Apostle Paul [viz Eph 4:13].
...the current "move" of the Spirit was the latter rain that would bring the Church's work to completion and culminate in the imminent Second Coming of Jesus Christ.

...the belief that Christians will have more and more power within society, mainly driven through miracles, even that "church agendas" will take precedence above or even replace political issues.
Branches vary within Latter Rain, but they generally believe this to some degree. The central trait is that their homily is generally devoid of—and hotly opposed to—any notion of wide-spread Christian martyrdom as Jesus's Return approaches.
Personal Experience
There can be a non-published, unacknowledged flavor to these movements.
Beyond that, this Personal Experience section is supplemental to documentation and serves superfluous further explanation, but no conclusions depend on this section.
At this time, neither that pastor nor his church state up front that they teach "Latter Rain" or that they teach against so-called "Negative Prophecy"; they merely enforce these undiclosed ideas behind closed doors with a heavy hand. I may reach out to them for a chance to be up front about this.
In my experience, not ever able to be documented...
Followers and teachers may argue that Christian martyrdom happens because the Church has not grown powerful enough. This is because not enough people have been "in obedience" to become "Manifested Sons of God" by obeying the special leader who has all five parts of the "Five-Fold Ministry".
In politics, many may believe that finding the good Christian leader is the most important election question while other political matters are less-significant because the church will basically take over the world anyway. Economy, infrastructure, education, free speech, civil rights, etc are all problems that will go away if we just "submit to the church leaders". This is not merely wanting "godly virtue" in political leaders, but specifically believing that special "Five-Fold" church leaders will appoint leaders to replace all others as part of their eschatology. They avoid and discourage discussion on politics, but this is not because they are neutral, rather they believe their appointed Manifested Sons of God will replace the government before Jesus comes back.
They may differ on beliefs about the Rapture of the Church, as long as any belief does not have wide-spread Christian martyrdom. Again, this is only consistent across conversations, nothing able to be well documented.
Concerning prophecy, all prophetic messages must only be shared with permission and approval of church staff or official leaders. This resembles how Jan Hus was expected to pray to God through a priest, not pray to God directly.
Again, these can't be documented because they rarely state these ideas publicly on record, only in the private conversations where they enforce these ideas.
"Negative Prophecy" plays a key role in these unofficial conversations. Its primary residence is behind closed doors.
Motive for Latter Rain to oppose "Negative Prophecy"
Rejecting so-labeled "Negative Prophecy" is in the interest of the two Latter Rain points above.
"Negative prophecy" becomes a convenient label so that...

Their special leaders who choose prophets, teachers, etc can't be opposed "because that's negative".
Any scary belief about martyrdom can be dismissed "because that's negative".

So, use of the term "Negative Prophecy" within Latter Rain circles is not only coincidental, but has a clearly definable motive. Dismissing "Negative Prophecy" is very useful for Latter Rain leaders to respond to standard dissent.
Conclusion: a defense for profiteering spiritist-charisma
As the accepted answer observes, the cited rhetoric examples from today seem to have roots in Africa, Nigeria in particular.
The "positive-negative" lens of philosophy created by Hill is at the earliest traceable beginnings of the self-help genre, which is not always bad, but certainly is not a Christian church doctrine.
Being a "positive" person is among Biblical commands—count blessings, bring joy, love, peace, etc. But, "positivity" is not a religious doctrine; it is a motivator.
Generally, being a "positive person" makes more friends and sells more stuff. "Positivity" is a form of "charisma", an interpersonal talent, not the family of denominations.
The origin of Positivity also overlapped with a disingenuous approach to making money. Ironically, fraud isn't a positive thing. Teaching people to be positive while committing something negative like fraud is a form of doublespeak, a tool of dishonest profiteering.
Money and a "positive outlook" are not bad things, but dishonest money is profiteeting and passing "positivity" as a religious concept are misleading.
In the more radical branches, we may find more than a prosperity gospel (promising wealth to believers), but a profiteering gospel (doctrinally engineered to make teachers & leaders rich).
The concept of "Negative Prophecy is a convenient Latter Rain rebuttal against dissent. Prosperity gospel and Latter Rain often overlap.
Not having any review from an established Christian tradition, identifying it as a defense for profiteering spiritist-charisma is accurate for now.

1. Eagleson, Claire (March 2016). "The power of positive thinking: Pathological worry is reduced by thought replacement in Generalized Anxiety Disorder". Behaviour Research and Therapy. 78: 13–18. doi:10.1016/j.brat.2015.12.017. PMC 4760272. PMID 26802793.
2. Chang, Edward C., ed. (2001). Optimism & pessimism implications for theory, research, and practice (1st ed.). Washington, DC: American Psychological Association. pp. 101–125. ISBN 1-55798-691-6.
3. Racy, Famira; Morin, Alain (January 2024). "Relationships between Self-Talk, Inner Speech, Mind Wandering, Mindfulness, Self-Concept Clarity, and Self-Regulation in University Students". Behavioral Sciences. 14 (1): 55. doi:10.3390/bs14010055. ISSN 2076-328X. PMC 10813701. PMID 38247707.
4. Dobbins, R.; Pettman, B.O. (1997-01-01). "Self-development: the nine basic skills for business success". Journal of Management Development. 16 (8): 521–667. doi:10.1108/02621719710174011. ISSN 0262-1711.
5. Moriarty, Michael (1992). The New Charismatics. Zondervan. ISBN 978-0-310-53431-0.
6. Kenneth E. Hagin, New Thresholds of Faith, (Tulsa, OK: FLP, 2nd edn, 1985 [1972]), p.56.
7. Warnock, George (1951). Feast of Tabernacles. Sharon Publishers.

Not trying to answer my own question, these are only further considerations after not seeing any other answers providing any basis in Christian doctrine history. I still regard the other answer as more likely the best answer.
